# How to handle timeout(--ms-- message) in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This photo shows `--ms--` message. And in client side, I get `timeout` error.

[image]

I am trying to figure out where it occurs and why using `try-catch` and `console.log` but I can't find any.

This is 'routes/email.js'

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../db');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'ssssss@gmail.com',
    pass: 'SSSSSS'
  }
});

router.get('/send', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('/send');
  var email = decodeURI(req.query.to);
        console.log(email);
  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000 + 1000));
  var link="http://"+req.get("host")+"/email/verify?email="+email+"&num="+rand;
  var mailOptions={
                to : email,
    subject : "Please confirm your Email account",
    html : "Hello,<br> Please Click on the link to verify your email.<br><a href="+link+">Click here to verify</a>"
  }

        try{
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.json({result:false,message:"Incorrect email", code:404});
        }else{
                console.log("Message sent:\n"+JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
                                try{
                                        console.log(JSON.stringify(db, null, 2));
                                                                                var sql = "INSERT INTO email_verification(email, code) VALUES(?,?)";
                                        var input = [email, rand];

                                        db.get().query(sql, input, function(err, result){
                                                if(err) res.json({result:false, message:"SQL error", code:403});
                                                res.json({result:true, message:"Please check your email.", code:100});
                                        });

//                                      res.json({result:false, message:"DB ERROR", code:401});
                                }catch(e){
                                        console.log(e);
                                }
        }
        });
        }catch(e){
                console.log(e);
        }
});

module.exports = router;
```

`db.get().query()` part doesn't execute at all.

This is `db.js`.

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');

var pool;

exports.connect = function(done){
        console.log("Trying to connect DB...");
        pool = mariadb.createPool({
                host: 'localhost',
                user: 'root',
                password: 'ssss',
                database:"SSSS",
                connectionLimit: 100
        });
}

exports.get = function(){
        console.log("exports.get");
        return pool;
}
```

The `console.log("exports.get");` parts works fine.

This is `app.js`:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var db = require('./db');

//var passport = require('./passport');
//var auth = require('./routes/auth');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

db.connect(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        if(err){
                console.log('Unable to connect to MariaDB.');
                process.exit(1);
        }
});

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', require("./routes/index"));
app.use('/email', require("./routes/email"));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        var err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
  next(404);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I just used this `db.js`and `app.js` file from my other project and it worked fine there. But I don't know why this time I have this problem.

Which part and why I am having this problem and how can I fix it?

- It'd be easier to work with node.js if I can track the error easily. Figuring out the problematic part takes lots of time. Is there any module or tool for that?